# Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 608941808256

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have enabled YouTube data API and Google+ API for my project and change the Android API Key in Auth.java I also entered my playlist info into Constants.java. However I still get this unhelpful error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
  {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=608941808256"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
}
```

can some one help me please

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you get the solution for it? Please share it if you got solution

Answer (score 57):

We had the same issue. We resolved it by starting from scratch and creating a brand new API project. For some reason the existing API project didn't work. Steps to check if you have this issue:

- Create a new project in the API console (click the project dropdown at the top of the window, and choose "New project").
- Enable the APIs required (e.g. YouTube Data).
- Go to credentials->Domain verification and enter your domain.
- Fill in the OAuth consent screen, and make the "application name" the same as your project name. Also choose the scopes you will be using, add your domain, save it, and submit for verification.
- Create credentials of type "OAuth2 client key->Web application" and enter the correct callback uri.
- Wait a few hours.

You should now be able to test in the APIs explorer (enter your own client key).

Comment: This also fixed my issue! I didn't have to wait a few hours — it was ready to go immediately.

Comment: Fixed it for me. It seems once your API access is automatically disabled due to a period of no use, the daily requests quota turns to 0, and there is no way to get it back to normal, so you are left with sort of a zombie project, even if you don't realize it at first - since Google don't really tell you that. (In fact, their API reply implies you can re-enable access by visiting the project - this is not true, at least the moment). The only thing to do is to create a new project with a new API key and new quotas.

Comment: Yeap, created new project from scratch. It worked. 
Thanx!

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me too. The keys from the existing project would not work even though they're set up just like the new project. Go figure.

Comment: I had the same issue! Like @Danra said above, it seems the old account is disabled somehow and can't be fixed. I used another project on which I had never used the YouTube Data API before, and that worked!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here.
Besides enabling the Google+ API and the Contacts API I have also to create a new OAuth Client Key for Web applications.

When you create it you'll see that the client id will start with the Project Id that you have on the error message.

In summary you'll have to do as follow:

1. Create an OAuth Client Key with type web application
2. And the Client Id to you API

Then you should be able to authenticate.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks @Leonardo Diniz, I stuck since 2 days

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow below steps:

1. Go to => https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=608941808256
2. Go to `Enabled APIs and services`
3. Click `YouTube Data API v3`
4. Click `Enable`

Comment: I recommend to use the code formatting for the URL, because it is part of the solution. You want to avoid the wrong impression that you link to the answer externally.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this problem by creating a new project and then creating new credentials

Comment: you ould have just configured it, instead of going through all of the hustle and creating a new project.