# YouTube Data API Queries quota limit auto change to 0

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My all active projects Queries quota limit auto set to 0. and can not edit it from 0 to more.

[image: screenshort]

First Receive email (Nov 9, 2018) with subject `"FYI, YouTube may disable your inactive project(s)"`

Receive Second Email (Dec 13, 2018) with subject `"[Final notice] YouTube may disable your inactive project’s access to YouTube Data API Service"`

- My projects already active. however google send me email notification.

after receive second email all api key not working and Queries per day set to 0.  when try to set new quota limit on console.developers.google.com then get error `"Enter a number below 0". only accept "0"` value not 1 too.

when try to use api key then get bellow error response:

```
"Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 230XXXXXX..."
```

who can help me?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a software development question as defined in the [help]. Only Google knows the definitive answer to this question. Please see [[Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

**You need to make a new google cloud project.** I'm not aware of a way to raise the quota after Google sets it to zero.
The cause of this issue might be inactivity of your project. According to the [developer policy](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#d.-accessing-youtube-api-services), "YouTube reserves the right to disable or curtail your access to, or use of, specific YouTube API Services if your API Project has been inactive for 90 consecutive days."

 You might be able to avoid this issue in the future by using https://www.cronasaservice.com/ to schedule a job to make API calls periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this related [SO post answered by Ninj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483674/youtube-api-v3-shows-access-not-configured), it says that inactivating or reactivating API will destroy your key validity. Here is the steps you will need to follow to solve the error: `"Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 230XXXXXX..."`:

> - destroy your server key (delete it completely, do not only regenerate)
> - deactivate then reactivate all APIs you need
> - create a new server key
> - thank Google for the so clear error messages (optional)

Hope this helps to change the error in quota limit.

Comment: Dose't work.. after delete and create new key. but new key generate with limit 0. and   quota edit but not clickable. showing message : "this limit may not be edited"
 what next step?

Comment: Could you upload the screenshot of your error so that I can check your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. And they guide that we have to request reactivation by filling this form. (below link)

You can find this guide in the Email you received when the YouTube team notify you to deactivate your project.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5HxReFtxATJLNfLwQiucfQwYL295Xemgc6nhFXo1vcitg3A/viewform

So I filled the form but there is no answer and I'm waiting. I think this is the only way to reactivate or you can create a new project for using YouTube Data API.