# YouTube Queries per day becomes to 0

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use my project with the API around two years and works fine.

But I get error recently.

```
{'error': {'errors': [{'domain': 'usageLimits', 'reason': 'dailyLimitExceeded', 'message': 'Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas?project=', 'extendedHelp': 'https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas?project=562388912346'}], 'code': 403, 'message': 'Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas?project='}}
```

I check my google console api and find out the Queries per day becomes to 0. The strange thing is it can't be edited.

[image]

I looking for some solutions, but it seems someone still won't work, and I don't want to delete my project server key, if I have choice.
[Youtube API v3 shows "Access Not Configured"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483674/youtube-api-v3-shows-access-not-configured)

And I check my email to see there is any about quota information I miss from YouTube, the funny thing is I have a mail in 11/08/2019, and it is about increase my quota not adjustment to 0...

```
Dear YouTube API Developer,

As part of ongoing YouTube API Services management, we have adjusted the YouTube Data API Service quota assigned to your API Project Number: 1019XXXXXXXXX

Over the last 90 days, the peak daily quota usage that your API Project used to access/use YouTube Data API Service was 397940 quota points per day.  Based on this, your quota has been adjusted to 400000 quota points per day. Please note, this is higher than your peak historical usage in the last 90 days.

You don’t need to make any changes unless you need to use more quota than what is allocated to you. In that case, please use the standard quota request form found in the Google Cloud Console.

If you have other YouTube Data API project(s) for your other API Client(s), please check their new quotas in the Google Cloud Console.

Thanks,

YouTube API Services team
```

I have send a request form to YouTuBe again (last time is two years ago).
But it looks like we can't sure about we have a response or not.
https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/9522041?hl=en

Just want to know someone have another solutions about the issue ?

Comment: I have run into the same problem. Were you able to resolve this? If so, how?

Comment: It is the only way Send the form to YouTube https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form and wait. They will response to you if they have some questions, it will take about three or seven days. I just get approve yesterday, but it still shows zero.  I have to send the same form and ask why it still shows zero... What a night mare :(

Comment: Anything new with the api?

Comment: @LukasNeumann
Yes, they give me response, I found I get the permission on my another google account.

Comment: Deleting the project and creating a new one solved for me

Answer (score 9):

Not the greatest answer, but the only one which works, is to create a new project and switch your app over to using that.

For some reason once you get "quota exceeded" errors and "daily limit = 0" on GCP you are cursed forevermore. Lots of people asking this question and no-one seems to have a solution.

Creating a new app doesn't take long and will fix the problem. Sorry I don't have better news for you :(

Comment: Creating a new project dosen't work for me i still have 0 Queries per day. I haven't made any request to any google service in like a year. Digging out an old project. EDIT for some reason deleting my old project gave me quota on my new one. Thanks

Comment: Creating a new project worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Oh my gosh.. how dumb is this. Now I am going to have to create 20 apps.. hahah. how does that solve the problem Google. its a bit mental